# Get minimum oriented bounding box from partial point cloud from depth sensor

Tags: computer-vision, ros, point-cloud-library

How can I compute the oriented bounding box from a partial point cloud?

My use case is I have a depth camera looking down at a table with one object (which can have irregular geometry). The camera does not get the full point cloud because the bottom of the object is occluded.

From the limited point cloud information I can get, how do I fit a oriented bounding box around it?

I intend to use the bounding box to calculate center of mass, assuming uniform density, and using this as a grasping heuristic.

Similar question in 2d: [minimal bounding box of a clipped point cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152204/minimal-bounding-box-of-a-clipped-point-cloud)

Answer (score 1):

If i get you right why don't you assume following:

1. reproject visible points to a planar surface (table)
2. get bounding rectangle around reprojected points (unseen points must
   be inside of it and can't be outside if camera is orthogonal to
   projection surface, table in this case), this is a bounding box profile
3. bounding box bottom is the table and its top is parallel to it and contains the nearest point to camera

Comment: This is interesting. But is there really no general method to get the 3d bounding box without this planar assumption?

Comment: 3d task is identical to 2d but with one more space. But to start with planar assumption is easier to understand and visualize. Also it's computationally more effective.

Comment: How do you get the orientation for the 3d version?

Comment: Is there any ros package to do this?

Comment: I'm no familiar with ROS, but there might be at least for 2d case. And for 3d you will just use it twice for (x, y) and (y, z) planes.
I think you can't get orientation for z axis id you don't see all points on it. Find oriented bounding box for (x, y) plane and assume z in range (0, max(z)).